# Convert .dbf .prj .shp .shx to GeoJson

Tags: gdal, shapefile, dbf, ogr

I have all those files containing data and i want to convert all the data into a single geojson file.

I am trying to do it like so:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -s_srs pga.prj pga.geojson pga.shp
```

but i think it's not doing what it should. I do get a pga.geojson file but it just contains a rectangle:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features":
  [
     {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties":
        {
           "AREA": 0.000000,
           "PERIMETER": 0.000000,
           "PGAPOL_": 2.000000,
           "PGAPOL_ID": 1.000000,
           "GRID_CODE": 2.000000,
           "VALUE": 0.020000
        },
        "geometry":
        {
           "type": "Polygon",
           "coordinates":
           [
             [
               [ 20.000000, 48.000000 ],
               [ 29.000000, 48.000000 ],
               [ 29.000000, 43.000000 ],
               [ 20.000000, 43.000000 ],
               [ 20.000000, 48.000000 ]
             ]
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

I think the file should allso contain some lines which do not seem to appear. What else should i do in order to make it use the data from all the files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collectively, those files are called an "[ESRI Shapefile](http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html)". The minimum required are .shp, .shx and .dbf, but there may also be .prj, .sbn, .sbx, .fbn, .fbx, .ain, .aih, .ixs, .mxs, .atx, .shp.xml, or .cpg files (no kidding!) Typically, you only refer to the .shp file, but the other files must be present in the same directory.

To show the feature data, with the geometry in [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), try using the ogrinfo tool:

```
ogrinfo pga.shp pga
```

If you see similar data, then that's the data that it should be, unless you were expecting something else.

Comment: How do you install orginfo ? I know this is a really old question.

Comment: @SurajSubramanian there are many ways, have a search.